# Nice way to access value in ruby nested hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following nested hash. How can I quickly access the `result_api` value, if `listing_id` is `variable`?

```
 {"0"=>{"result_api"=>15229, "listing_id"=>4}, "1"=>{"result_api"=>15229, "listing_id"=>2}, "2"=>{"result_api"=>15229, "listing_id"=>1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
h.find{|k, v| v['listing_id'] == @var}[1]["result_api"]
```

First you `find` relevant result and get two-element array `[key, value]`, then you access the values using `[1]` and then you access the key you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
hash = { "0" => { "result_api" => 15229, "listing_id" => 4 }, 
         "1" => { "result_api" => 15229, "listing_id" => 2 }, 
         "2" => { "result_api" => 15229, "listing_id" => 1 } }

hash.values.find{ |h| h['listing_id'] == @var }['result_api']
```

Answer (score 2):

Although **[mrzasa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446992/nice-way-to-access-value-in-ruby-nested-hash#answer-49447142)** and **[Szymon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446992/nice-way-to-access-value-in-ruby-nested-hash#answer-49447308)** both's answers will work for you, but if `@var` contains such value which is not any `listing_id` in your `hash` it will gives you an error.

> NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass

OR

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

**Instead** I prefer below way:

```
# valid value
> var = 4
> h = hash.detect{|k,v| v["listing_id"] == var}
> result = h.last["result_api"] if h
#=> 15229

# Invalid value
> var = 54654564
> h = hash.detect{|k,v| v["listing_id"] == var}
> result = h.last["result_api"] if h
#=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't consider that!